# Delete duplicate records based on two columns in MySql

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I want to delete the extra duplicate record

i.e. in the image shown there are two records with `corporate_id = 5` and `category_id = 19`, how to delete any one row which is duplicate (here `corporate_sed_id` is the primary key)

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this :-

```
DELETE
FROM
    corporate
WHERE
    corporate_sed_id IN(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            MIN(corporate_sed_id)
        FROM
            corporate
        GROUP BY
            corporate_id,
            category_id
        HAVING
            COUNT(corporate_sed_id) > 1
    ) temp
)
```

Comment: I have solved this problem through different way, but just to check your solution I have executed this query and this worked like a charm :) Thank you @nikita

Comment: thanks :) @K Arun Singh

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks !

Comment: @KArunSingh it would have been nice if you had shared your solution...

Comment: This will only remove one duplicate if there are several with the same id, right? One would have to run it multiple times to remove all duplicates. Is there a way to make it work for any number of duplicates (i.e. only keep one)?

Comment: It's also useless if you don't have an id, like in a pivot table

Comment: @theberzi you can switch the IN into NOT IN. if you run the select * it will return the smallest corporate_sed_id from duplicates, means if you want to left only one from many duplicates, NOT IN will do the trick. Although you also need to check again the HAVING condition in case you have mixed data with no duplicates.

Comment: It worked, however for a huge dataset I noticed it does not delete all the duplicates at once, you have to run it several times as it returns a number of affected rows. A good suggestion on this would be, to run this statement in a **PHP loop** until it returns 0 rows.